# Is 'some_program <some_file' faster than 'cat some_file | some_program'?

Tags: io-redirection, pipe, cat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I care about unnecessary cats?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16279/should-i-care-about-unnecessary-cats)

Both would be functionally equivalent, but when using cat wouldn't it be slower because you have a process first reading the file and then sending it through a pipe to another process, instead of the process just reading the file? But I've seen this usage 'cat file | program' in a lot of examples. I assume they wouldn't use it that much in examples if it had bad performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but the bigger slowdown would be starting up the first process(`cat`).

However, seeing as how the difference is minimal on any computer made in the last 15 years that isn't loaded down very heavily(load avg < 30), the bigger disadvantage is code readability.

Comment: A big +1 for the practical advice, focusing on readability.