# Why pipe to cat only to redirect?

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, cat

I occasionally see things like:

```
cat file | wc | cat > file2
```

Why do this?

When will the results (or performance) differ (favourably) from simply:

```
cat file | wc > file2
```

Comment: Just a [useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Useless_use_of_cat#Useless_use_of_cat).

Comment: They may be useless uses of `cat` but I like for the input file to be the leftmost thing and for the commands that operate on it to appear after it.

Comment: http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/cat-tobacco-pipe-6986596.jpg

Comment: @chicks just nit picking, but `cat` would still be the leftmost thing and the file it's operating on would appear after it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I care about unnecessary cats?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16279/80216)  See also [Remove useless-uses-of-cat or not?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/1261/80216)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
cat file | wc | cat > file2
```

would usually be two useless uses of `cat` as that's functionally equivalent to:

```
< file wc > file2
```

---

However, there may be a case for:

```
cat file | wc -c
```

over

```
< file wc -c
```

That is to disable the optimisation that many `wc` implementations do for regular files.

For regular files, the number of bytes in the file can be obtained without having to read the whole content of the file, but just doing a `stat()` system call on it and retrieve the size as stored in the inode.

Now, one may want the file to be read for instance because:

- the `stat()` information cannot be trusted (like for some files in `/proc` or `/sys` on Linux):

  ```
  $ < /sys/class/net/lo/mtu wc -c
  4096
  $ cat /sys/class/net/lo/mtu | wc -c
  6
  ```
- one wants to check how much of the data can be read (like in case of a failing hard drive).
- one just wants to obtain benchmarks on how fast the data can be read.
- one wants for the content of the file to be cached in memory.

Of course, those are exceptions. In the general case, you'd rather use `< file wc -c` for performance reasons.

---

Now, you can imagine even more far fetched scenarios where one may want to use: `cat file | wc | cat > file2`:

- maybe `wc` has an apparmor profile or other security mechanism that prohibits it from reading or writing to files while it's allowed for `cat` (that would be unheard of)
- maybe `cat` is able to deal with large (as in > 2<sup>32</sup> bytes) files, but not `wc` on that system (things like that have been needed for some commands on some systems in the past).
- maybe one wants `wc` (and the first `cat`) to run and read the whole file (and be killed at the very last minute) even if `file2` can't be open for writing.
- maybe one wants to hide the failure (exit status) of opening or reading the content of `file`. Though `wc < file > file2 || :` would make more sense.
- maybe one wants to hide (from the output of `lsof` (list open files)) the fact that he's getting a word count from `file` or that he's storing a word count in `file2`.

Answer (score 37):

Both of those examples are [useless uses of cat](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html).  Both are equivalent to `wc < file1 > file2`.  There is no reason to use `cat` in this example, unless you are using `cat file` as a temporary stand-in for something that dynamically generates output.

Comment: Ha, didn't even catch the first one. Thanks for link :) bookmarked to read the other "useless uses of ~" later.

Comment: The first usage of `cat` is *not* necessarily useless here. The command `wc file` prints the counters *followed by the name of the file*. The command `cat file | wc` does *not* print the name of the file. The second `cat` is useless. `wc file1 file2` prints two lines of counts, one for each file (plus the file names). `cat file1 file2 | wc` prints one line with the total counts, and no file names.

Comment: @alephzero Reread the answer- `cat file | wc` is equivalent to `wc < file1`.

Comment: @IstvanChung: Interestingly, on my system they're actually *not* equivalent.  `cat file |wc` separates the line/word/character counts with more spaces than `wc <file` does.  I don't know why.

Comment: @IstvanChung: They're not equivalent. `wc < file1` causes `wc` to run with stdin being a file descriptor for a regular seekable, mmappable file, `file1`. `cat file1 | wc` causes `wc` to run with a non-seekable pipe on stdin.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence. Often, a "useless" `cat` is a handy placeholder to be able to pop other commands in and out without rearranging the pipeline.

Comment: @alephzero +1, but, danger danger: If `file1` does not end in a linefeed, then `cat file1 file2 | wc` will count one fewer lines, and potentially one fewer words, than would `wc file1 file2` (which sees the "break" between `file1` and `file2`).

Answer (score 17):

While I don't disagree with the argument for saying it is a 'useless use of cat', there **can** be reasons for it:

In many languages (including English) words and sentences are read from left to right, so showing the flow of data in the same way can appear more natural to the reader.

A reason for the second `cat` could be to mask the return code. Such as:

```
$ wc < /etc/passw
sh: /etc/passw: Cannot find or open the file.
$ echo $?
1
```

Whereas with `cat`:

```
$ wc < /etc/passw | cat
sh: /etc/passw: Cannot find or open the file.
$ echo $?
0
```

This can come into play if the shell has `set -e` set. In the first example,  this would abort the shell after `wc` whereas in the latter example it would continue on. Obviously there are other ways of dealing with this.

Also, the performance difference of the two statements (ie with or without cat) is negligible (esp. on today's machines) and if it was important, shell is the wrong language to use.

Comment: You make an interesting point, but it's hard to see when one is blinded by the enigma of `wc < /etc/passw` giving two completely different messages in contexts that are essentially indistinguishable.

Comment: @Scott - That's a good point. It is a quirk of AIX - I'll use a different OS instead.

Comment: Interesting remarks. Just my note to the left to right representation of the flow of data: You can easily achieve this with redirection too: `< file1 wc > file2`

Comment: @pabouk - woah! i did not know you could do that.

Comment: What @pabouk said: redirections can appear anywhere on the command line, at least in GNU bash, so "reading left to right" is not a valid argument for using `cat` instead of a redirection.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling starting the command with '<' looks like you are redirecting to the shell itself.

Comment: @DarkHeart Which is then.. "auto-piped" to `wc` :p Thanks for an answer on "the other side", leaving larsk's accepted as for me - and it seems generally - `cat` is not necessary here. But yours is a useful reference for behaviour with it, or scripting where it can easily be replaced by something else. (In particular I can see it being useful for say a "variable command" - might want to default, or change it to "nothing" without modifying the rest of the script.)

Comment: This is... not a great idea in practice.  If you want to swallow errors, `|| true` is a lot more idiomatic and obvious than `| cat`.

Comment: This also assumes `set +o pipefail`, which is POSIX, but a common bash recommendation (and good idea IMO) is to set it, i.e. `false | true` (note pipe not `||`) should fail.

Answer (score 10):

Let's suppose `prog` forks a new subprocess and exits, and the new subprocess writes something to its standard output and then exits.

Then the command

```
prog
```

won't wait for the subprocess to exit, and it will display the shell prompt early. But the command

```
prog | cat
```

will wait for an EOF on the stdin of `cat`, which effectively waits for the subprocess to exit. So this is a useful use of `cat`.

Comment: Valid point, at least for `bash`. To test it one may run `( (while ((i<10)); do echo $((i++)); sleep 1; done) &  exit ; ) | cat` with and without final `cat`.

Comment: On the other hand, with shells like the Bourne shell, AT&T ksh or yash, `prog | cat` could return _before_ `prog` has returned (In those shells, it will return as soon as `cat` returns, which will happen as soon as `prog` (and its children if any) has closed all its fds to the pipe)). Try for instance with `prog` being `sh -c 'echo A; exec >&-; sleep 2; echo >&2 B'`.

Answer (score -1):

The statement contains two uses of cat.

> **cat** file | wc | **cat** > file2

Clearly the 2nd cat is of no value, as

> **cat** file | wc > file2

has the same meaning in all shells I have ever used.

However

> < file wc > file2

does not work in **all** shells.

Not everyone is using a modem shell on a modem version of unix.   (It can be off benefit to write pipeline in a way that work on all systems that have the commands in the pipe installed, even if some of these commons don't ship as standard with the given OS.)

Comment: `< file wc > file2` is Bourne and POSIX and also works in (t)csh, rc and es. The only shell I could find that doesn't support it is `fish` (which is the most modern of them all). It even worked in the pre-Bourne sh of Unix V1 in 1970!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, you are assuming that scripts only have to work on "unix"!

Comment: As far as this unix.stackexchange.com Q&A site is concerned, that's Unix-like systems yes (though other POSIX systems are also covered). And as far as this question is concerned, you'd expect a system where `cat` (a typical Unix command) is available.